# JavaScript error "Invalid Argument" only in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, arguments

I am only receiving an error on IE8 where my menus are not loading up on the home page. All the other browsers are fine.

The IE gives me this "Error on Page":-

```
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 2
Char: 66850
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
```

Strangely, it's in Jquery, but actually it's some parameter that's being passed to JQuery which triggers the error.

Upon investigating, I found the following line, which throws the error:-

```
"this.parentNode.insertBefore(a,this.nextSibling"
```

This was about the error, now I've no clue where it triggers within the code. Upon some tries, I found a strange scenario within my code, at the point where I am creating the menus:-

```
`
"node-1" : ['Overview/2','Overview/3','Overview/4','Overview/5','Overview/6','Overview/7','Overview/8','Overview/9','Overview/10','Overview/11','Overview/12','Overview/13'],


"node-2" : 
['node/2/1','node/2/4','My-Perspective/Opportunity-for-RMEP','node/2/2','node/2/5','node/2/6','My-Perspective','My-Perspective/2','My-Perspective/3','My-Perspective/4','My-Perspective/5','My-Perspective/6','My-Perspective/7','My-Perspective/8','My-Perspective/9','My-Perspective/10','node/2/7',/*'node/2/44a','node/2/44b',*/'node/2/43','node/2/44','node/2/45','node/2/46','node/2/47','node/2/48','node/2/49','node/2/8','node/2/9','node/2/10','node/2/11','node/2/12','node/2/13','node/2/14','node/2/15','node/2/16','node/2/16a','node/2/16b','Value/Transportation','Value/Transportation/1','Value/Transportation/2','Value/Transportation/3','Value/Transportation/4','Value/Transportation/4b','Value/Outbound-logistics','Value/Outbound-logistics/2','Value/Outbound-logistics/3','Value/Outbound-logistics/4','Value/Outbound-logistics/5','Value/Outbound-logistics/6','Value/Outbound-logistics/7','Value/Inbound-logistics','Value/Inbound-logistics/2','Value/Inbound-logistics/3','Value/Inbound-logistics/4','node/2/50','node/2/51','node/2/52','node/2/53','node/2/54','node/2/55'],//,'node/2/56','node/2/57','node/2/58','node/2/59','node/2/60','node/2/61'],


"node-3" : 
['My-Experts/1', 'My-Experts/2', 'My-Experts/3', 'My-Experts/4', 'My-Experts/5', 'My-Experts/6', 'My-Experts/7', 'My-Experts/8', 'My-Experts/9'],//'vince-lima','dave-mcmurray','ron-gewin','bill-parr'],


"node-4" : 
['My-Way/Potential','My-Way/Potential/2','My-Way/Requirements','My-Way/Requirements/Business-Led-Approach','My-Way/Requirements/Integrative-Transformation','My-Way/Requirements/Systematic-Waves','My-Way/Junk','My-Way/Junk/Relevant-Examples','My-Way/Junk/High-Tech','My-Way/Junk/High-Tech/2','My-Way/Junk/High-Tech/3','My-Way/Junk/High-Tech/4','My-Way/Junk/High-Tech/5','My-Way/Junk/High-Tech/6','My-Way/Junk/Retailer','My-Way/Junk/Retailer/2','My-Way/Junk/Retailer/3','My-Way/Junk/Retailer/4','My-Way/Junk/Retailer/5','My-Way/Junk/Basic-Materials','My-Way/Junk/Basic-Materials/2','My-Way/Junk/Basic-Materials/3','My-Way/Junk/Basic-Materials/4','My-Way/Junk/Basic-Materials/5','My-Way/Junk/Basic-Materials/6','My-Way/Junk/Automotive', 'My-Way/Junk/Automotive/2','My-Way/Junk/Automotive/4','My-Way/Junk/Automotive/5','My-Way/Approach','My-Way/Approach/1','My-Way/Approach/2','My-Way/Approach/3','My-Way/Approach/4','My-Way/Approach/5' ],

"node-135" : 
['Why-me/My-Capabilities/We-have-the-most', 'Why-Me/My-Capabilities/We-have-the-most-2','Why-Me/My-Capabilities/Sample-Profiles','Why-Me/My-Capabilities/We-bring-proprietary-tools','Why-Me/My-Capabilities/My-Consultants-Combine','Why-Me/My-Capabilities/My-Consultants-Combine-2','Why-Me/My-Capabilities/My-DTV-Labs','Why-Me/My-Capabilities/My-Chicago-Lab','Why-Me/My-Capabilities/IT-Systems','Why-Me/My-partnership'],

"node-145" : ['Tools/1','Tools/2','Tools/3','Tools/4','Tools/5','Tools/6','Tools/7','Tools/8','Tools/9','Tools/10','Tools/11','Tools/12','Tools/13','Tools/14','Tools/15','Tools/16','Tools/17','Tools/18','Tools/19','Tools/20','Tools/21']
`
```

When I remove the last node (node-145), the page doesn't give any error, but still doesn't show the menus.

Comment: ...and other browsers aren't reporting anything in the error console? The line you quote that throws the error is missing a closing parenthesis - but I assume that is a typo??

Answer (score 2):

In IE8, bring up developer tools, click on the "Script" tab, click on the "Start Debugging" button, and refresh the page in the browser.  The browser will execute the code and then break on the line causing the problem.  While this is not a specific answer to your question, this will be much more specific and give you a lot more information about how to fix your error than the error message in the console.